# Getting "no such file or directory" bash error when trying to compile a file

Tags: bash, files

I have already checked out the many similar questions on this website, but I keep getting this error when trying to run my program conversion.cpp with ./conversion.

The program is here: [image]

(i can't seem to copy paste the text)

Whenever I run the program, I get the error that there is no such file or director. I have already tried chmod to no avail.

Any help would be great appreciated!

Comment: How did you compile it? `g++` or `gcc`?

Comment: use `./conversion.cpp` instead of `./conversion`

Comment: No.  You can't run a c or c++ program without compiling and linking it first.  It's not a scripting language like php, or python.

Comment: I'm really new to do this and naturally I don't have right terminology but I just used gedit conversion.cpp wrote the program in that window, and went back to the original script to run it.

Comment: When I used ./conversion.cpp I get this http://puu.sh/biCF9/c9fb344b84.png

Comment: The steps are the following: Create the .cpp, compile it (gcc), then run the created executable (./executable)

Comment: [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Compile-a-C/C%2B%2B-Program-on-Ubuntu-Linux) and [this Q/A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61408/what-is-a-command-to-compile-and-run-c-programs)

Answer (score 3):

You must compile your .cpp file into a binary file, `chmod +x` the resulting binary file, then run the compiled binary. You can do this easily with the following syntax:

```
g++ <cpp file> -o <resulting binary file>
```

i.e. the following for your particular program:

```
g++ conversion.cpp -o conversion
```

Example:

```
mgodby@mg-ws1:~/code$ g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
mgodby@mg-ws1:~/code$ ls
helloworld  helloworld.cpp
mgodby@mg-ws1:~/code$ chmod +x helloworld
mgodby@mg-ws1:~/code$ ./helloworld 
Hello World!
mgodby@mg-ws1:~/code$
```

Note 1: If your compile fails for some reason, make sure that all necessary packages are installed -

```
sudo apt-get -y install g++
```

Note 2: You must re-compile, i.e. run the `g++` command again, every time you make a change to the original .cpp file, else the changes you make will not take effect.

The reason that you cannot run your .cpp file directly is that c++ is a "compiled" language and not a "scripting" or "interpreted" language. If you'd like to know more about this particular distinction, you can refer to the following article to get the basics:
[Interpreted language - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language)

Comment: No problem. Remember to mark the answer as "Accepted", please.  ;)