# How do I run my C program?

Tags: programming, c

I am a newbie in C programming language. I am following a course right now, but I have a small problem which is run the file for testing.

I have opened gedit and I wrote those lines of code:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    puts("Hello world.");

    return 0;
}
```

and when I try to run it after giving the right permissions with this command

```
chmod +x file.c
```

and run by this command

```
./file.c
```

those lines show up in terminal

```
./file.c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./file.c: line 1: `int main (int argc, char *argv[])'
```

**Where is the problem ??**

Comment: You can't run the source file, you have to compile it first. I'm sure this is covered in your course.

Comment: Please look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/61408/what-is-a-command-to-compile-and-run-c-programs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to compile your program before you can run it. To do this, you'll need a C compiler, like `gcc`. You can install this with:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Then, to compile your program, creating an executable called `file`:

```
gcc -Wall -o file file.c
```

Which you should then be able to run:

```
./file
```

Comment: GCC is so basic that it's installed by default in Ubuntu as part of `build-essential`, so is installed already; technically `sudo apt-get install gcc` updates it.

Answer (score 3):

Fabrice Bellard's TCC seems to be still in the repositories. It can run in a kind of interpreter-mode which makes the following possible:

You can make a simple C-file executable like the OP tried to do by adding the line

`#!/usr/bin/tcc -run`

to the very top of the file.

It also accepts input from STDIN by adding an empty option (just the minus sign `-`) at the end.

```
$ /usr/bin/tcc -run - <<EOF
> #include <stdio.h>
> int main()
> {
>    printf("Hello World\n");
>    return 0;
> }
> EOF
Hello World
```

or with `echo`

`echo  '#include <stdio.h> int main(){printf("Hello World\n");return 0;}' | /usr/bin/tcc -run -`

or just run `/usr/bin/tcc -run -` type your code and start the run with `CTRL + D`

Seems useless and silly but the last method is the fastest (for me, YMMV etc.) to check for a function in a large library, look up the exact value of a constant etc. And it is small (180k) which makes it a good fit for e.g. the Raspberry-Pi.

Main disadvantage: development stopped (last version is from 2013).

Comment: There goes my clear distinction between compiled and interpreted languages. Oh my... ;).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you have to compile C code before executing it like so:

```
gcc file.c
```

Answer (score 0):

C language unlike python is not an interpreting language. The C source code or simply the code written need to be compiled first to make it executable i.e, machine readable form.
You have to first compile it by using command

> cc -Wall filename.c

cc - GCC compiler

-Wall - Checks for error

filename.c - your file in which C code is saved with .C extension.

You will get an executable file named "a.out" in the working directory of your source code.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a small problem which is run the file

To answer your question:

> Where is the problem ??

it is enough to say that you cannot run the executable file yet because you have not yet produced it. Your file, `file.c`, is the "source code" written in the language of "C". This source code is not something that is executable because the C language was designed to be writeable in an easy to understand way (at least 'easy' by human standards... even then, it's not easy at first - but it get's easier). The (source) code you write is then converted into a form that a computer can read easily. This process is called 'compiling'. Compiling creates a file which is **executable** by a computer. It is this step that you have not done. If you type

```
which gcc
```

and you get back something like `/usr/bin/gcc` then you have gcc already installed on your system. If you get back nothing - then you dont. If you don't have gcc then you can get gcc (provided you have the correct privileges) by doing:

```
sudo apt install gcc
```

(NB: apt might not work if you're on some older release of the linux distribution - you can replace it with `apt-get`)

If you **do** have `gcc` then go right ahead and type:

```
gcc file.c
```

and you will find an *executable* file called `a.out` has magically appeared in your directory. This is the file you've been looking for. Run it with

```
./a.out
```

The other answers have other things like `-o` and `-Wall` which you can learn about through the manual for `gcc` which you can access by typing:

```
man gcc
```

That should keep you going for a couple of years... welcome to coding - Enjoy!