# How to install C compiler in version 15.10?

Tags: c

I've searched many methods, but couldn't find best C compiler. Earlier, I used Win7. In that, I've used Turbo C/C++ v4 compiler. It will open in DOSBox. So, I've installed DOSBox in Ubuntu 15.10. I've pasted the same folder (which I used in Win7) on desktop. Opened TC.exe from BIN. Its text editor is running, but it is not compiling the programs....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run my C program?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/693650/how-do-i-run-my-c-program)

Answer (score 1):

"Open C"? What do you mean? And how would you "install C"? You don't need DosBOX for that, and I think you have a misunderstanding.

You can create your C code and use tools such as GCC (GNU Compiler Collection) to **compile** it. I think that's what you mean.

You can install GCC and some other basic development/building tools with the package `build-essential` in Ubuntu.

To install it with APT, make sure you have the "main" repository enabled in Software and Updates and run, in a terminal:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: I'm unable to find GCC in Ubuntu Software Center. So I've got and idea of using C compiler by DOSBox. I've installed DOSBox, copied the C folder to Desktop. Then I've opened TC.exe from BIN folder. Its text editor is working. But when compiling, its not getting compiled and the header files are not getting included for the program...

Comment: Is there any alternative to install C/C++ compiler on Ubuntu 15.10? I've searched many applications in Ubuntu Software Center. (Thanks for your answer)

Comment: As I said, GCC is part of the `build-essential` metapackage in Ubuntu.

Comment: Mind if you could help me in creating, running and executing C programs?

Comment: Sorry, this kind of question does not belong here. If you want to develop C programs you should have some minimal knowledge about it. What I can tell you is to get build-essential, write your C source code and compile it with GCC.

Comment: Where can I get GCC?

Comment: As I said (two times), it is part of the `build-essential` metapackage.

Comment: Bro, I'm a student. I'm using Ubuntu for the first time. I've installed it 3days back. Could you explain me how to open, create, run, compile C programs in Ubuntu 15.10?

Comment: @SaitejaVemula ___Install `build-essential` using the command provided in the answer and then you can use GCC.___ There isn't much to it.

Comment: @SaitejaVemula And please do not ask questions such as "how to install C in x Operating System". If you want to deal with C, please study how it works and learn it before. Sorry, that's all I can tell you.