# Simple C hello world program is not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am fairly new to C coding and cannot get a simple C hello world code to work with Visual Studio Code. The code looks like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   // printf() displays the string inside quotation
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

and I get two error messages:

```
line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
line 2: `int main() {'
```

Any suggestions on what can be going wrong?

Comment: Seems you have incorrectly configured the build task for the file. Since VS Code relies on file name for auto-detection of build tasks, what is the file name of this source code? Which build task are you selecting when you click Ctrl+Shift+B? Do you see any logs in the in-built terminal of VS Code? The error seems to be from BASH which obviously can't compile C programs.

Comment: hi, the file name is simply test2.c, but i dont get any option to select anything when ctrl+shift+b. The terminal says: "> Executing task: /usr/bin/gcc-9 -g /home/myname/Downloads/test2.c -o /home/myname/Downloads/test2 <  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it

Comment: OK so VS Code has compiled the code. Did you run any command and encountered the mentioned error?

Comment: I am just doing ./test2.c in the directory i have saved it

Comment: You have to compile the c-code, and then run the a.out binary file ...

Comment: @user1146311 That's what you're doing wrong :) VS Code created an executable with name as `test`. You need to run that executable not the C code. If you want to do that from VS, either define a new task or follow the below answer. But if you want to run from terminal, see [How do I run my C program?](https://askubuntu.com/q/693650/816190)

Comment: @SorenA You don't have to do anything but right clivk this code and select *Run Code* to run it in Visual Studio code.

Comment: @SorenA I assume OP is trying to run the executable created by VS. VS creates executable with the name same as the source code (due `-o` in task definition) unless build task is modified. So, `a.out` might be irrelevant unless OP compiles using `gcc fileName` only.

Comment: @Kulfy Thank u very much, it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a screenshot of the C code in the question (hello.c) running correctly in Visual Studio Code. In order to run hello.c in Code Runner right-click the code and select *Run Code*.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Please note in the left pane that I have the C/C++ extension and the Code Runner extension installed in Visual Studio Code. Please note in the tabs below the menu bar that the C code has been saved in a file named hello.c. Please note in the bottom pane that Code Runner executed this C code by running the following command:

```
cd "/home/karel/Desktop/" && gcc tempCodeRunnerFile.c -o tempCodeRunnerFile && "/home/karel/Desktop/"tempCodeRunnerFile
```

Comment: I dont have Code Runner or the C++ intellisense extension. Will try again with those downloaded