# Terminal not outputting result in Visual Studio Code

Tags: nodejs, visual-studio-code, javascript

[image]

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm learning Node.js. When testing my installation of node.js and VS code, I just wanted to run a `console.log('Hello');`, but the terminal is not outputting anything when I run the file.

In the terminal I just wrote: `node hello2.js`

`hello2.js` is the name of the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple C hello world program is not working in Visual Studio Code](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290855/simple-c-hello-world-program-is-not-working-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 1):

I am very dumb. I forgot to save the file. Do people recommend to turn on autosave?