# Why do I get a "Permission denied" error every time I try to execute a C++ program?

Tags: permissions, c++, g++, execute-command

Every time I try to execute a program, no matter what program, I get this message:

```
bash: ./filename.cpp: Permission denied
```

When I compile I have no problems, it works fine. But when I want to execute I get this message.

Does it have anything to do with permissions? Because I'm having a lot of problems with this, too. I can't access my shared folders, unless I use

```
sudo nautilus
```

Please see my [other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711734/problem-with-shared-folder-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: Try `chmod u+x program_name` where program_name is the programs name. And then execute the program.

Comment: You can't just run a .cpp file you MUST compile it, it is not a bash script it is a program.. As for your shared folders, what are there paths ?

Comment: @Steamgamer I have already tried that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @markkirby I compile everytime, but then I can't execute. The shared folder is in computer/media/ but everytime I click on it I get this message "This location could not be displayed. You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "sf_sharedfolder".

Comment: To be clear, are you talking specifically about programs that you have compiled? What *exactly* are you typing (a) to compile them and (b) to run them. Please be specific i.e. use the **real** names of files.

Comment: Are you trying to compile/run programs on a virtualbox shared folder? it is likely that the sf_ filesystem doesn't support the necessary Unix permissions

Comment: You are executing the wrong file, the compiled file is a .out file, by default it is called a.out and goes to your home folder, run the a.out not he .cpp. You can't access your sheared folders as user because root owns /media, what are they sheared from/with ?

Comment: @steeldriver I'm talking about specific programs that I've compiled, but I think I have a problem with execution in general, because I tried to create new programs, compile and execute them, and they don't work either. My program is main.cpp. When I compile it I type g++ -c main.cpp, then I trype ./main.cpp and I get that "permission denied" message.

Comment: @markkirby When I type ./a.out I get this "bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory"  Am I typing it wrong?

Comment: That's simply **not** how to compile and run a C++ program: you do `g++ -o yourprog main.c` then `./yourprog` - do *not* add the `-c` flag to the `g++` command unless you want it to produce an object code file instead of a full executable. See [What is a command to compile and run C++ programs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61408/what-is-a-command-to-compile-and-run-c-programs)

Comment: I am doing an answer with simple steps to compile and run cpp code.

Comment: @steeldriver When I use g++ main.cpp -o main I get a list of  "relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11, relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12" and so on

Comment: As these issues are unrelated, please make a new question asking about you sheared folder permissions.

Comment: @Francesca the *"relocation"* errors suggest your `main.cpp` file does not actually contain a `main` function: see [Linker returns “relocation has an invalid symbol at symbol index…”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766256/linker-returns-relocation-has-an-invalid-symbol-at-symbol-index)

Answer (score 5):

To compile and run a `.cpp` file in Ubuntu, follow this example guide

First we need a `.cpp` file, we will save it as `main.cpp` and in `home/user/documents`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
cout << "Hello World!";
return 0;
}
```

If you need it install `g++`

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Now we have an program, we can go to `Home/user/documents` and compile it

```
cd ~/Documents
g++ main.cpp
```

This will produce a file named `a.out` in your `/home/user/Documents` directory

Now run the `a.out`

```
./a.out
```

Output will be

```
Hello World!
```