# How to run a .cpp in my ubuntu server?

Tags: server, client

I would like to run my server.cpp and client.cpp in my ubuntu server, someone can guide me in this ? I try ls(list) in my user in ubuntu server and it is empty. I want to import those files and execute the cpps. THankss !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a command to compile and run C++ programs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61408/what-is-a-command-to-compile-and-run-c-programs)

Comment: Are these files on the same machine in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t run .cpp files the way they are. You have to compile them. You can use `g++`. It can be installed using apt on the package with the same name. If you’re not sure how to use it then see this question: [What is a command to compile and run C++ programs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61408/what-is-a-command-to-compile-and-run-c-programs)

From your question it sounds like your code was written on a different machine than the server. So you should get the files onto the server. If you physically can access it, use a USB drive or other storage medium. If you have a cloud instance or some other type of remote server, normally you should be able to ssh into it. So you can use `scp` to copy your files. 
The syntax is:

`scp -P <port> file-to-copy user@server:/where/to/put`

Afterwards you should be able to run your code.

If you’re still a bit confused about `scp` you can try looking at this article: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-scp-command-to-securely-transfer-files/

Hope this helps!